# Chrome 66+ SVG doesn't update colors after stylesheet change

Tags: css, svg, chromium

Perhaps my implementation of this is a little misguided as I am not an SVG expert, but after Chrome 66+ update, an SVG on my page that is styled using CSS properties does not update colors.

Here's an example:
`Aqua Theme -> Blue Theme`

[image]

Markup:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="MainMenuSwoosh">
    <path d="M100,100           L100,0            C50,25 75,100 25,100z" fill="url(#SwooshGradient)"></path>            
    <defs>
          <linearGradient id="SwooshGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
               <stop class="stopBottom" offset="0%"></stop>
           <stop class="stopTop" offset="100%"></stop>
          </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

LESS:

```
.MainMenuSwoosh {
    width: 4%;
    float: right;
    height: @mainMenuHeight;

    #SwooshGradient .stopBottom {
        stop-color: @altColor;
    }

    #SwooshGradient .stopTop {
        stop-color: @mainColor;
    }
}
```

I've found a decent solution to be swapping out the innerHTML for itself, using browser detection for Chrome 66+ but obviously I don't want to do this anymore.
JavaScript for swapping theme:

```js
$("#ddCurrentTheme").change(function (e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#DefaultCss")[0].href = val;

  /* hack for emulating "stylesheet loaded event", see onerror below */
  var img = document.createElement('img');

  function styleSheetLoaded() {
    try {
      window.dispatchEvent(MyEvents.ThemeChanged);
    }
    catch (ex) {
      //custom events not supported
    }

    var v = Telerik.Web.Browser.version;
    if (Telerik.Web.Browser.chrome && v && v >= 66) {
      $(".MainMenuSwoosh").html($(".MainMenuSwoosh").html()); 
    }
  }

  img.onerror = styleSheetLoaded;

  img.src = msg.d;
}
```

All of this "works" for me right now. The only new code I've had to add is the innerHTML swapping at the bottom, but I'm really hoping there's a better solution for this. This doesn't happen in other browsers as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry, what doesn't work exactly? [This works just fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/fdx9s6qx/) on chrome 66. And your hack is... unintelligible for me at best. Why don't you use postMessage if you want a 0 second timeout? And why don't you simply use `setTimeout`, are these possible 4ms really that important?

Comment: The part that doesn't work is swapping the `link` href for a new "theme".

Comment: Would be very good if you could [edit] your question to make it clear that it's what you are trying to do because nothing can let us understand that.